# Ошибка LNK1561: точка входа должна быть определена

Tags: c++

Что означает эта ошибка?

> `1>  LINK : не найден или не выполнена сборка c:\users\cs\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ролролгл\Debug\Vwe.exe при последней инкрементной компоновке; выполняется полная компоновка
> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1561: точка входа должна быть определена`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможно вы создали пустой проект, пользуясь мастером Visual Studio, и пытаетесь его скомпилировать и слинковать. А так как он не имеет метода main (для консольного приложения) и т.п., то сборщик и сообщает об ошибке.

Либо используйте другой шаблон проекта, либо добавьте в проект файл содержащий точку входа.

Answer (score 3):

Правая кнопка мыши на Проект -> Свойства -> Компоновщик -> Все параметры -> Подсистема.
Выберите - "Консоль".
Также не забудьте о `main();`

Comment: 1. Вопрос `задан 22 фев '12 в 17:29`. 2. Имеется уже принятый, то есть полностью устраивающий вопрошающего, ответ.

Comment: @Arhad ответы на SO даются не столько ради вопрошающих, сколько ради посетителей, которые придут из поисковиков. Принятый выше ответ, по сути - "пересоздайте проект". Подход Little Fox, очевидно, гораздо проще и удобее.

Answer (score 1):

Если у тебя консольное приложение, надо определить main, а если оконное приложение Windows, то WinMain.