# Помогите решить ошибку "LNK1561: точка входа должна быть определена"

Tags: c++

Вот мой код:

```
float x, y, z, a;
cout << "Введите a, x, y";
cin >> a;
cin >> x;
cin >> y;
z = log(abs(pow(x, 5)+exp(log(4)*y)))/(2*a*a+1)-pow(x, 3)*y+exp(x+y);
cout << z;
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка 1 error LNK1561: точка входа должна быть определена

Comment: @Yura1991, для разметки кода используйте начальный отступ в 4 символа. Посмотрите мою ревизию вашего вопроса для примера.

Answer (score 3):

Эта ошибка говорит о том, что функция main не объявлена. Объявите функцию main чтобы получилось так:

```
void main(){
    float x, y, z, a;
    cout << "Введите a, x, y";
    cin >> a;
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    z = log(abs(pow(x, 5)+exp(log(4)*y)))/(2*a*a+1)-pow(x, 3)*y+exp(x+y);
    cout << z;
}
```

И не забудьте подключить файлы заголовков для использования cin и cout функций:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Answer (score 2):

@Yura1991 учись пользоваться поиском google и т.п.

да и про поиск на самом хешкоде не забывай

[собственно нужна главная(стартовая функция)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/82719/c-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-lnk1561-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) main || winmain

Answer (score 1):

Точкой входа в C считается функция main. Есть ли у Вас эта функция?